# ExecJS::ProgramError: SyntaxError: Reserved word "function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In our rails rfq.js.coffee, we only have a simple js code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#need_report').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == true) {
      $('#report_language').hide();
    }  // end if
  });  // end change()
});  // end ready(function)
```

However this code causes an error saying that function() in first line is a reserved word. Since the first line is basically a jquery `$(document).ready(function () {})`, we have no clue why this error shows up. Any thoughts about it? Thanks so much.

Comment: Wait, is this CoffeeScript? Why are you using normal JS in CoffeeScript?

Comment: http://js2coffee.org/ will be your friend

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't use standard JS like that in a Coffeescript file. Either rename the file to `rfq.js`, or convert it to coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $('#need_report').change ->
    if $(this).val()
      $('#report_language').hide()
```

Comment: Just renamed the file to js file. Thought js can be used in coffee script without any change. Also found a site to convert the js to coffee script or vise verse. http://js2coffee.org/  thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's not like Sass vs CSS where you can use standard CSS inside an scss file.

Comment: However, after renaming the rfqs.js.coffee to rfqs.js, there is a strange error saying illegal character on line 9574 (There is only about 100 lines code in application.js) in application.js. I renamed the file name back to .coffee and the error disappeared. Strange enough!

Comment: I don't understand. According to the CoffeeScript site: "You can use any existing JavaScript library seamlessly from CoffeeScript (and vice-versa)."

Answer (score 8):

You can embed regular javascript by surrounding the code with back-ticks "`".  I wish it worked like the other parsing languages as well...it took me lot's of unnecessary debugging and searching to figure that out.  http://coffeescript.org/#embedded

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you wrote JavaScript code into file with extension `.coffee` you can use [js2.coffee](http://js2.coffee/) to convert your code from JavaScript to CoffeeSecript